Causal Mediation analysis, mediators and CMAverse
I am conducting a non-randomized study to evaluate the differences in complication rates between two treatments. The observed complication rates differ significantly between the two groups (22% vs. 50%). To account for potential confounders, I implemented a multivariable binomial logistic regression. Potential confounders were identified on a clinical basis using a Directed Acyclic Graph (DAG). Among the collected variables, I also identified three potential mediators: cholecystectomy, General_anesthesia, and treatment_approach. All of these are categorical variables (cholecystectomy and General_anesthesia are binary, while treatment_approach has three levels). Although they are significantly associated with the treatment (Fisher’s exact test p < 0.05), only cholecystectomy shows a strong association with complications (Fisher’s exact test p < 0.01).
Question 1: Can I consider all of these variables as mediators even if they are not statistically correlated with the outcome in my population?
Question 2: Cholecystectomy is highly correlated with one treatment (all cases except one occur in the control group). Can I still consider it a mediator? If not, what is the correct way to justify its exclusion from the mediator analysis?
I tried to implement a mediation analysis using the R package CMAverse, but when I included cholecystectomy as a mediator, the estimates were unreasonably high.
Below the code for the mediation analysis:
mediators_used <- c("General_Anesthesia", "cholecystectomy", "treatment_approach")
mreg <- list("logistic", "logistic", "multinomial")        
mval <- list("Yes", "Yes", "Open")                         

# 10 boots are used for illustration
mediator_analysis <- cmest(data = mediator_df, 
model = "rb", 
exposure = "Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder", 
outcome = "complications", 
mediator = mediators_used,
basec = c("Treatment_type_tumor_near_gallbladder", "sex", "comorbidities", "Systemic_treatment_prior_local_treatment", "Segments_treated_per_session", "Metastasis_size_at_treatment_mm", "min_distance_gallblad_mm"), # "ASA", "age", "bmi", "stage_binary" (removed for high correlation)
EMint = TRUE, # a logical value indicating the existence of exposure-mediator interaction
mreg = mreg, 
yreg = "logistic",
yval = list("Yes"), # the value of the outcome at which causal effects on the risk/odds ratio scale are estimated (used when the outcome is categorical
astar = "Resection", # the control value for the exposure. 
a = "MWA",   # the active value for the exposure. 
mval = mval,   # a list specifying a value for each variable in mediator at which the variable is controlled
estimation = "imputation", 
inference = "bootstrap", 
nboot = 10, # Increase to 100 or 200
multimp = TRUE, 
args_mice = list(maxit = 50, method = "polyreg", seed = 123)
)

Thank you in advance for your help!
